# how to fix safety net api warning in android studio

Tags: android, api, kotlin, warnings, safetynet

I am developing kotlin project,  when i upload release bundle in google console, following warning arised. How to fix this warning?

1 MESSAGE FOR VERSION CODE 49
Warning
The developer of play-services-safetynet (com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet) added the following note to SDK version 17.0.1:
The SafetyNet Attestation API is being discontinued and replaced by the new Play Integrity API. Begin migration as soon as possible to avoid user disruption. The Play Integrity API includes all the integrity signals that SafetyNet Attestation offers and more, like Google Play licensing and better error messaging. Learn more and start migrating at https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/deprecation-timeline

Learn more about the SDKs that you're using and make informed SDK choices with Google Play SDK Index.

Answer (score 0):

As warning says some part of Android API used by your project is deprecated, you are softly pushed to migrate to the new API.

To fix this issue you have to do this migration. Docs you have shared contains [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/migrate).